# first get values then check for null in onCreate() method

Tags: java, android

In my **LoginActivity.java** i am ***retrieving data from another activity and putting in TextView(s)***, as well as i am **checking for null for the same TextView(s)** in **onCreate() method**.

I want whenever LoginActivity.java calls first retrieve data from another activity, then set to TextViews, and after that check for condition.

I have written code for everything - **to check for condition, for retreiving values and to set values to TextViews**.

but whenever i am calling LoginActivity.java it **always checking for condition first**, but i **want to get and set values to TextViews first**, ***then check for condition*** in **onCreate() method**.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        btnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        btnGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGallery);

            txtDeviceID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDeviceID);
            txtEmailID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmailID);      
            txtEvent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEvent);  
            txtOperative = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOperative);
            txtEventOperator = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEventOperator);

             Intent intent = getIntent();
             deviceID = intent.getStringExtra("deviceID");
             emailID = intent.getStringExtra("emailID");
             event = intent.getStringExtra("name"); 
             operative = intent.getStringExtra("firstName");

             txtDeviceID.setText(deviceID);
             txtEmailID.setText(emailID);
             txtEvent.setText(event);
             Log.d("LA...event", txtEvent.getText().toString());
             txtOperative.setText(operative);
             Log.d("LA...operative", txtOperative.getText().toString());
             txtEventOperator.setText(event + "  " + operative);

             strEvent = txtEvent.getText().toString();
             strOperative = txtOperative.getText().toString();

            // Dialog
                final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                AlertDialog ad = adb.create();

                // new Class DB
                final myDBClass myDb = new myDBClass(this);

                // Save Data
                long saveStatus = myDb.InsertData(
                            txtDeviceID.getText().toString(),
                            txtEmailID.getText().toString(),
                            txtEvent.getText().toString(),
                            txtOperative.getText().toString(),
                            txtEventOperator.getText().toString()
                            );

                if(saveStatus <=  0)
                {
                  ad.setMessage("Error!! ");
                  ad.show();
                  return;
                }   

                // Show Data
                String arrData[] = myDb.SelectData();
                if(arrData != null)
                {
                    txtDeviceID.setText(arrData[1]);
                    txtEmailID.setText(arrData[2]);
                    txtEvent.setText(arrData[3]);
                    txtOperative.setText(arrData[4]);
                    txtEventOperator.setText(arrData[5]);
                }  

                if(txtEvent.getText().toString().equals("") && txtOperative.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {

                    Intent intentCall = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LicenseListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentCall);
                }

     }
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: how can i handle that ?

Comment: but you try first set to Textview and then check that, can you describe better your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your condition in onStart method

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
if(condition)

}
```

whenever activity is created onCreate method first call then onStart method.